# Can not update observable of one viewModel from another

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

I want to update one observable of one viewModel from another. The value gets changed but it does not reflect on UI (in HTML)

I am not sure what's wrong with the code..

Here is the code :

http://jsfiddle.net/rahulrulez/RSL4u/2/

```
<p data-bind="text: name"></p>
```

does not gets updated.

Comment: Can you use a view model that contains the two sub view models ?

Comment: Is that what you want to do ? http://jsfiddle.net/RSL4u/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried all your approaches, for some reason they were not really working with the solution I have.

After a lot of googling and digging deep in KnockoutJS documentations and extensions, I found **Knockout Postbox** which lets us sync or communicate between multiple irrelevant View Models.

https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-postbox

Here is snippet of my demo example...

```
var viewModel1 = function(){
   var _self = this;
   _self.name = ko.observable("Rahul").syncWith("syncedName");
}

var viewModel2 = function(){
   var _self = this;
   _self.firstName = ko.observable("Rahul").syncWith("syncedName");

}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel1(), document.getElementById("div1"));
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel1(), document.getElementById("div2"));
```

Both the observable are in sync now.. I found this much better than nesting objects.. At least it satisfied the need of my application..

Thank you so much for help anyway..

My Demo : JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/rahulrulez/2kuSh/1/

I hope it helped..

Thank you so much,

Rahul Patil.

Answer (score 2):

You are binding to two **independent** view-model instances

```
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel1(), document.getElementById("firstViewModel"));
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel2(), document.getElementById("secondViewModel"));
```

So there is no connection between your `viewModel1` and `viewModel2` and when you write in your `viewModel1`:

```
var vm2Object = new viewModel2();
```

then you are creating a completly new `viewModel2` instance which has nothing to do with the one used in the `applyBindings`.

To fix this you need to make a connection between your view models, somehow like this (there are multiple other ways to do like using a container view model, nest your view models to each other, etc.):

```
var viewModel1 = function(vm2){
   var self = this;
   var vm2Object = vm2; //use vm from parameter
   //...
}
```

And when calling the `applyBindings`:

```
var vm2 = new viewModel2();
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel1(vm2), document.getElementById("firstViewModel"));
ko.applyBindings(vm2, document.getElementById("secondViewModel"));
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cmjQL/1/).

Answer (score 1):

You have two different instances of the VM2 ViewModel. Instead do

http://jsfiddle.net/RSL4u/4/

I have made VM2 a sub model of VM1

```
this.vm2Object = new viewModel2();
```